# Perfect way to use variables in package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-scripts

I have a number of angular environments, like `prod`, `dev` and i would like to reuse this information in `package.json` scripts.
for example I have a profile 'dev` which contains:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    basePath: 'http://localhost:8001'
  };
```

and i would like to reuse this information in `package.json` under `scripts`

```
"scripts": {
  "generate-stub": "openapi-generator generate -g typescript-angular $basePath"
```

In such a way so I could just `npm run generate-stub --configuration=dev`.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am perfectly aware of .env and environment variables but since angular provides a dedicated way for configuration - prefer to stick with it and do not replicate logic.
At the same time it would be easier for users since there will be a limited set of profiles, less mess for CI/CD, less chance of error.
But, I'm completely new in npm/nodejs.

Is there any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run this command from a js script, something like that:

generator.js

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const config = process.argv.slice(2) // arguments
if(config === 'dev') {
 const basePath = enviroment-dev.basePath;
} else {
 const basePath = enviroment-prod.basePath;
}
exec(`openapi-generator generate -g typescript-angular ${basePath}`);
```

and in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "generate-stub": "node ./generator.js"
```

then you can run command with your argument `npm run generate-stub --configuration=dev`

This code are not tested, but just for giving your an idea!

success!